# python cumsum with reduce function

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a version of cumulative sum in python using the reduce function. Here is my code so far:

```
from functools import reduce

def my_cum_sum(arg):
    return reduce(lambda a, x: (a.append(a[-1] + x)) if len(a) > 0 else a.append(x), arg, [])

assert(my_cum_sum([1, 1, 1, 1]) == [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

But the problem is that in my lambda function, python doesn't know that a (my accumulator parameter) is a list object, and that I want my reduce function to return a list. In other functional programming languages, it might ask me to specify the type of `a` and `x`. But I'm new to python, and haven't quite figured out how it handles types and stuff. What is the pythonic way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`append` returns `None`, so you cannot get the list back into `reduce` like this.
Just use the addition between the list and a list made of a single element, or just a list made of initial element if list is empty:

```
from functools import reduce

def my_cum_sum(arg):
    return reduce(lambda a, x: a + [a[-1]+x] if a else [x], arg, [])

print (my_cum_sum([1, 1, 1, 1]))
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

(note that `if len(a)>0` is better written `if a` as well)

Comment: Why do you use a[-1]?

Comment: this is the current last element of `a`

Comment: But isn't "a" already a single element?

Comment: no it's the parameter of the lambda passed by reduce so it's a list. Try it out

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Python's accumulate (although this doesn't explicitly use `reduce`)?

```py
from itertools import accumulate

def my_cum_sum(arg) -> list:
  result = accumulate(arg)
  return list(result)

assert(my_cum_sum([1, 1, 1, 1]) == [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the lambda do the append and then return the list.

```py
from functools import reduce

def my_cum_sum(arg):
    return reduce(lambda a, x: a.append(a[-1] + x if a else x) or a, arg, [])

assert(my_cum_sum([1, 1, 1, 1]) == [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU9LCoMwFNznFLM0NBZsuyiCJxGRV01awZiQD-hZunHTHqC36W2q1EKHWQ3DfO5PO4WbGeb5EYNKz--XckZDxaEJxvQenbbGBTjZxkYy1koFPdVN1LWPOiF35TnDAidDdMPmS3rSl5ZAAmMO2pO1cmgTKtOswg4jOgWC7L3EyGHcalyiBMqKM0beSxeSv5oyE9hYcRQFVuEgcBQ4Vfy7fDvwO_IB)